# To copy lines of a text file to list in python

Tags: python, list, text

My File has the following four lines:

First line
Second line
Third line
Fourth line
Last line

I want to search this file for the word "Third" and copy the "First line" and "Second line" to a list1, then copy "Third line" to a list2 and finally the last two lines "Fourth line" and "Last line" to a list3.

Really, I was trying to do this simple using a 5 line file.  But really, I am using a file that has 1438 lines.  I am trying to copy this file in 3 different lists.  I want to be able to copy the all lines before "SATELITE" to one list and then all the lines that start with "SATELITE" to list 2 and finally the end lines to list 3.

I have use readlines to put all lines in a list, that is as far as I got.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into reading from a file?
Can you maybe show what you have tried?

Comment: Think about how you'd do this manually. For example, you might go line by line, adding lines to `list1` until one of them contains `Third`, then adding that to `list2`, then adding all of the rest to `list3`. All of that can be directly translated to Python. It might not be the most concise way to code it, but it will work. If you get stuck somewhere in translating any part of that, then you'll have a good question to ask.

Comment: Hi Ron, I have done this so far:

def ReadContent():
    file = open('testing')
    alllines = file.readlines()
    for i in alllines():
        if i == 'Third":

I got stuck there so far.

Comment: @pedro, update the question with that code so we can see it more clearly.   ...and that's 5 lines, not 4.

Comment: @pedro         Could you check my answer and see if this is what you had in mind?

Comment: @hagubear Don't advertise your answer. The OP is perfectly capable of finding the best answer for themselves.

Comment: i want a cookie, can you give me one? where is your code ...

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use the shortest version with list comprehension which is as follows:

```
with open(file_name) as f: # Default file operation mode is `r'
    items = f.readlines()

    i = [index for index, item in enumerate(items) if item.startswith('Third')]
    list1, list2, list3 = items[:i[0]], [items[i[0]]], items[i[0]+1:]

    print list1
    print list2
    print list3
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following code:

```
if "Third" in open(your_file).read()
   print("Found the word!")
   f1 = open(your_file)
   i = 0;
   list1 = [];
   list2 = [];
   list3 = [];
   for line in f1:
      i += 1;
      if (i < 3):
        list1.append(line):
      else if (i == 3):
        list2.append(line);
      else:
        list3.append(line);
```

Does this suit you? Also this is good only if the file is not huge!!!

Comment: he doesn't want the third entry, he wants to see if the text contains "Third"

Comment: @user3684792   edited answer. apologies

Comment: This still doesn't do what the OP asks...

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I am just typing this into the window without trying it (so there may be a couple of minor errors)

```
def process_file(path):

    list_container = [[] for i in range(3)]
    list_index = 0
    with open(path,'r') as text_file:
        for line in file:

            if "Three" in line:
                 list_container[1].append(line)
                 list_index = 2
            list_container[list_index].append(line)
    return list_container
```